# Access the remote control/Terminal Services properties of a windows user via c#

Tags: c#

I'm writing a C# program that adds Users on a Server 2003 box.
I user the .NET 3.5 namespace `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`, which is OK.

However, I'd like to prevent the added users to use Remote Control or Terminal Server log on rights.

Do you know how to do that in C#? I failed so far to find anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to remote desktop to a machine depends on the security policy of that machine.  By default members of the Administrators group and the Remote Desktop Users group (on the local machine) have the ability to remote desktop.